# Different behavior of the onclick attribute during form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, jsfiddle

Hello I came across a weird behavior with an onclick attribute regarding form submission.

**Page on Server:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en-us" >
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Return Form Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doSomething(){
            alert("hey");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" onclick="return doSomething()" value="click me!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, running on my server, when I click the submit button I get an alert saying hey and I stay on the current page.  However, I tried to set this same example up on jsfiddle and I get an 404 error meaning the form was submitted. I cannot figure out why this occurs.

Here is the jsfiddle where I am trying to replicate the behavior on my server.

**jsfiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/46XSv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check the option "`no wrap - in <head>`" which is "Do not wrap the Javascript code, place it in  section".

Select "`no wrap - in <head>`" under "Framework and extensions"

In this page you'll find the description of each of the options around the bottom: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html.

Also its a good practice to include semicolon at the end of your return statement, like the following:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return doSomething();" value="click me!">
```

Comment: Thank you! Now this makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onsubmit` on the `<form>` element instead of `onclick` on the `<input>` element. It will work correctly.

Comment: Ok thank you. This will practically solve my problem but I am wondering why my code works on my setup and not on jsfiddle. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the user interaction, I suppose it can behave differently not only on jsfiddle, but also on different browsers.